# Cifrar y descifrar una contraseña en Powershell

Tags: powershell

Estoy creando un script para notificar por correo el arranque de un servidor Windows 2012, la cosa es que el script como tal funciona, pero los credenciales del correo están en texto plano en especial la contraseña y me gustaría cifrarla y descifrarla de alguna manera para que en el script no se vea en texto plano y funciona sin problemas tal y como funciona ahora que envía el correo.

El campo que se tiene que cifrar es el contenido de: `$pass` y luego en la línea del final:

```
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$correoemisor", 
"$pass");
```

que la detecte correctamente, ya que sino la detecta en texto plano no funcionaría, así que tendría que cifrarse y luego descifrarse para que `$pass` en `SMTP.Credentials` funcione.

Os dejo el enlace por aquí por si alguien me puede echar una mano:

```
$fecha=$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d") #No modificar esta línea

$correoemisor = "pruebacorreocugo@gmail.com"
$correoreceptor = "pruebacorreocugo@gmail.com"
$pass = "contraseñacorreo"
$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"


$pc = Get-content env:computername

$mensaje = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true

$mensaje.From = "$correoemisor" 
$mensaje.To.Add("$correoreceptor")
$mensaje.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$mensaje.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$mensaje.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$mensaje.Subject = "Su sistema $pc se inició en $fecha" 
$mensaje.Body = "<h2> Su sistema se inició recientemente </h2>
</br>
Hola, su sistema con nombre $pc se inició hace unos momentos.
<br/>
" 

$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$correoemisor", 
"$credenciales.Password");

$smtp.Send($mensaje)
```

Gracias por la ayuda!